# Ruby unjumble words and match to dictionary

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, dictionary, permutation

I am trying to write ruby code that unscrambles the word entered and then match those word to a dictionary. The goal is to find match those words to dictionary and find a word in the dictionary and print it. This is how my code looks like.

```
print "Enter scrambled word here:"
Jumble = gets.chomp

a = Jumble.split("")
perms = a.permutation.to_a.collect do |perm|
perm.join
end

return perms

fin = File.open("dict.txt", "r")

while line = fin.gets
word = line.chomp

if word = word.downcase
    perms = word
    print perms 
end

end

fin.close
```

My code seems to work fine until "return perms".  it gives me error saying unexpected return (LocalJumpError).  i do not know if my code after that point is correct or not because i cannot get past that point.  I somehow need to get those perms and match them with the dictionary.  The first word that is found in the dictionary needs to be printed.  How do i go about that.

This is what the dictionary looks like:

```
words_un
Aarhus
Aaron
Ababa
aback
abaft
abandon
abandoned
abandoning
abandonment
abandons
abase
...
Zulus
Zurich
```

I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

```
return perms
```

Values (objects) get returned from methods, or functions. Technically you are not in a method, so Ruby has no idea what you are talking about.

Extra: technically you are inside the Object class, and you cannot return things from a class.